# Uploading Excel files to Memory (RAM), not the file system

Tags: .net, excel, upload

We're looking for a way to upload MS Excel files from a web page to memory.
We want to avoid saving the file to disk (because of virus issues). 
We can use .Net or a component if it is availalbe.

Detail: We have a web page, the page allows users to upload the Excel file.
We don't want to save the web file to RAM, we want to open it in memory.

Comment: please update the question with how you plan to *use* the file.  Do you plan to open it with excel or a 3rd party library?

Comment: @MusiGenesis: 1. He's talking about uploads, not downloads; 2. clicking such a link will download the document to a temp file and open it from there

Comment: This smells of Hilarious Misconception of The Month.

Comment: What makes you think it you're any safer from a virus if you just "open it in memory"?  You're not.

Comment: I am not able rightly to apprehend the kind of confusion of ideas that could provoke such a question.

Answer (score 12):

Viruses are harmless on the file system - they become harmful when they are executed, and stuff is always executed from RAM.

So you gain absolutely nothing by uploading into RAM, if ASP.net even allows that (how it handles file uploads is implementation specific, it may hold it in RAM or in a Temp File).

If you are worried about viruses, don't run the Excel file. Run a Virus Scanner, or go all the way and spin up a sandboxed Virtual Machine every time a file gets uploaded - depending on your exact usage and requirements.

Comment: +1 because you actually took the time to give a good answer to a ridiculous question.